# Find first index for value in List

Tags: c#, linq, list

In text I have some identical words and I want to get position for each word.
Using such construction:

```
fullText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);  
List<string> arr = fullText.Split(' ').ToList();
List<string> result = arr.
    Where(x => string.Equals(x, "set", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).
    ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(arr.IndexOf(result[i]));
}
```

I get only last position for each word.For example, I have:

```
**LOAD SUBCASE1  SUBTITLE2 LOAD SUBCASE3 SUBTITLE4 load Load Load**
```

and I must get

```
**LOAD : position 1 
LOAD : position 4
load : position 7
Load: position 8 
Load : position 8**
```

Comment: The title and content don't match. In the title you're asking for the first index of a value, while the question's content asks for **all** indices of the first value found (ignoring upper-/lowercase and special characters)???

Comment: Have you tried Console.WriteLine("position: " + (i + 1));  ?

Comment: yes,I tried such variant but I got only last index for each word.For example: Load Load must be 1 and 2 but I got 2 and 2

Comment: There is no "set" in your wordlist.

Comment: I've mistake, instead "set" must be "Load"

Comment: The problem here, is that `arr.IndexOf(result[i])` looks for an item that is equal to `result[i]`, but `string` comparison is done by value

Answer (score 2):

To get the index, try something like this;

```
List<string> result = arr.Select((s,rn) => new {position = rn+1, val = s})
         .Where(s => string.Equals(s.val, "LOAD", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
         .Select(s => s.val + " : position " + s.position.ToString()) 
         .ToList();
```

Above query will not return `**LOAD` and `Load**`. To get your expected results with `**` to the end, I think you could use `s.val.Contains()` as below;

```
List<string> result = arr.Select((s, rn) => new { position = rn + 1, val = s })
     .Where(s => s.val.ToLower().Contains("load"))
     .Select(s => 
        s.val.EndsWith("**") ? s.val.Substring(0, s.val.Length - 2) + 
        " : position " + s.position.ToString() + "**" : s.val + " : position " + 
        s.position.ToString())
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is no "set" in your wordlist. .... I've mistake, instead must be
>   "Load"

You are using `Equals` to compare. That means you want to compare the whole word, not part of the word, hence "**LOAD" would be omitted. Is that desired? Otherwise use `IndexOf`.

However, you can use this query:

```
var words = fullText.Split().Select((w, i) => new{Word = w, Index = i});
var matches = words.Where(w =>  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals("load", w.Word));
foreach(var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}", match.Index);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/0hltyN)

```
Index: 4
Index: 7
Index: 8
```

The `IndexOf` approach would be:

```
var partialMatches =  words.Where(w =>  w.Word.IndexOf("load", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1);
foreach (var partialMatch in partialMatches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}", partialMatch.Index);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/nMOEYh)

```
Index: 0
Index: 4
Index: 7
Index: 8
Index: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method that does the job:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> IndecesOf(this string text, string pattern)
    {
        var items = text.Split(' ');
        for(int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
            if(items[i].ToLower().Contains(pattern));
                yield return i + 1;
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
var fullText = "**LOAD SUBCASE1 SUBTITLE2 LOAD SUBCASE3 SUBTITLE4 load Load Load**";
foreach(int i in fullText.IndecesOf("load"))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Output:

> 1 4 7 8 9

Please note that I removed the double space from your example-string, when using a double space the split will add an empty string to the array.